# Can I have an image slide up to reveal more content with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

My client wants something like the "Become a Member" area at the bottom of http://www.sdchamber.org/.  (Actually she wants exactly the same thing, but I have no flash experience at all)  I am a novice at jquery, but it seems like it should be able to do something like this.  Can anyone help me out?  Have an image slide up to reveal content under?

Thanks!

Comment: site sdchamber is not flash, its also javascript + html

Comment: Looks like the site you referenced is using javascript to create that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `<div>` below the thing you want to hover over and `animate()` it to increase the height from `0px` to say `500px` or something on `hover()` and then you can animate it to decrease the height back to `0px` on `blur()`.

And you need to have a bigger div which contains both the hidden and non-hidden div's and add the `focus()` and `blur()` to this bigger div.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a div
2. Place another div within that contains the content to be displayed.
3. Place the image in the parent div with absolute position.
4. Use a hover event to trigger a slide up or something when the parent div is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a place to post this. StackOverflow is for answering specific questions. Please check out this forum where they can help you code the whole thing:

http://www.codingforums.com/forumdisplay.php?f=47